# How to compress image file in python?

Tags: python, optimization, compression, python-imaging-library

I am working on a file transfer project and I want the images downloaded from the server to be downloaded in the compressed form. How do I do it using python?
I want to use PIL Module to reduce the size of every image that the user downloads.

Comment: Your question is currently very vague. Please add some details. Why can't you just serve images that have their own compression, eg PNG format?

Answer (score 0):

This function will take input path of ur file and give output as zip file of all images to taht path

```
 def zipper(path):
        """
        This function archives the output folder for more than one image files
        """
        # check if more than one files are there in output path
        total_image_files = os.listdir(path)
        zip_file = path +"/img.zip"
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, mode='w')
        for fe in total_image_files:
            zf.write(path + "/" + fe, arcname = fe)
        zf.close()
        return zip_file
```